# Concurrent execution of a set of operation using Flux / Executor service

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor, threadpoolexecutor

I have a scenario to process list of customer numbers and update details in db

```
public void updateCustomerDetailsInDB(List<String> numberList)
for(String number : numberList){
    if(!isExistBy(number)) //Check the details of the customer in db by number
    {
    // if not exist call the customer retrieve API to get the customer details
    String response = customerClient.getCustomerRetrieveApi(number); // api call 
    dbService.persistCustomerDetails(response) // save customer details in db 
    }
}
```

```
// My CustomerRetrieveApi call using webclient 

       webClient.post()
                .uri(urlString)
                .contentType(mediaType)
                .bodyValue(requestObject)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(responseClass)
                .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
                        ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 404 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex))
                .block();
```

There will be 1000 numbers in the list. how can I execute it in parallel using executor and flux? and which would be better approach along with code implementation?

I tried with @async method and executor but its running only in single thread. I need at least 10 threads (10 numbers) running in parallel.

Example: In for loop 1 number takes 1s to complete the process so 1000 numbers means 1000s but I want the program to execute in 100s when the batch is 10.

Comment: Can anyone try with Elastic Bound and competable future and can say which has good performance ?

Answer (score 1):

To allow Reactor to optimize task scheduling you must avoid resorting to `block` operation. In general, you should try to avoid block as much as possible, because one of the main interest of Reactor is to provide "non-blocking" pipelines (block is provided for compatibility with external code/api).

In your case, you could:

1. Make `getCustomerRetrieveApi()` return a Mono, instead of blocking

   ```java
   public Mono<ResponseClass> getCustomerRetrieveApi() {
      webClient.post()
               .uri(urlString)
               .contentType(mediaType)
               .bodyValue(requestObject)
               .retrieve()
               .bodyToMono(responseClass)
               .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
                       ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 404 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex));

   }
   ```
2. Make your main loop reactive, by using `Flux.fromIterable(numberList)` and `flatMap`:

   ```java
   /**
    * @return count of updated details.
    */
   public Mono<Long> updateCustomerDetailsInDB(List<String> numberList) {
       return Flux.fromIterable(numberList)
           .flatMap(number -> {
               if (isExistsBy(number)) return Mono.just(0L);
               return customerClient.getCustomerRetrieveApi(number)
                             .map(response -> { 
                                     dbService.persistCustomerDetails(response);
                                     return 1L;
                                  })
                             .defaultIfEmpty(0L);
           })
           .sum();
   }
   ```

Now that might not be enough depending on `isExistBy` and `persistCustomDetails` implementation. But that is the first required step to allow reactor to properly transform your workflow into a non-blocking and concurrent pipeline.

Comment: How can I split it into batch in this and check the timings ?